# How to generate Endpoint to get CSRF Token from Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, csrf-token

For Requests to a Spring Boot Application made with Kotlin I need to get the CSRF Token,
to use them in subsequent requests against the Spring Boot Application.

As I understand CSRF protection is enabled by default.

```
    fun getCurrentCsrfToken(): CsrfToken? {
    val attr = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes() as 
    ServletRequestAttributes
    val session = attr.request.getSession(false) ?: return null

    return session.getAttribute("org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN") as CsrfToken
     }
```

But this returns null.

Does someone know how to get the CSRF token?

After I have a token I can provide it over an Endpoint.

```
    @GetMapping("/csrf")
    fun getPublicInfo(): ResponseEntity<String> {
    val token = getCurrentCsrfToken()

    return ResponseEntity.ok(token)
}
```

I tried the following approach as well, but it does not work:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = ["/csrf-token"], method = [RequestMethod.GET])
    @ResponseBody
    fun getCsrfToken(request: HttpServletRequest): String? {
    val token = request.getAttribute(CsrfToken::class.java.name) as CsrfToken
    return token.token
}
```

Comment: Any endpoint should return the CSRF token in a cookie called XSRF-TOKEN. As long as Spring Security is on the classpath